# REST API list_user

Tags: users, rest-api

I need to get a list of users by specific role.
I user this endpoint:

```
GET /users?roles=customer
```

but I got:

```
"code": "rest_user_cannot_view",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to filter users by role",
"data": {
    "status": 403
}
```

If I use "GET /users" works, but I have not the result I would and moreover I can't see all user in DB

Comment: The message says you are not allowed to filter users by their role, what is the role of the current user?

Comment: Filtering users by role requires [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) and the user making the API request also needs the `list_users` capability.